# Changing the icon of the back button on the Navigation Bar in .net MAUI

Tags: c#, android, .net, mobile, maui

I want to change the icon of the back button on the Navigation Bar in .Net MAUI. When I want to customize it with TitleView I don't get the result I want. Is there a way to change the icon of just this button?

I tried to make a custom bar with TitleView, but I didn't get the result I wanted.

Comment: Umm hide the existing one and use TitleView and adjust things i guess?

Answer (score 1):

From document [Back button behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation?view=net-maui-6.0#back-button-behavior):

> Back button appearance and behavior can be redefined by setting the
> `BackButtonBehavior` attached property to a `BackButtonBehavior` object.

The following code shows an example of redefining back button appearance and behavior:

```
<ContentPage ...>    
    <Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
        <BackButtonBehavior Command="{Binding BackCommand}"
                            IconOverride="back.png" />   
    </Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
    ...
</ContentPage>
```

The `Command` property is set to an `ICommand` to be executed when the back button is pressed, and the `IconOverride` property is set to the icon that's used for the back button.

You can also customize the `TitleView` by yourself. Here, we need to hide the default navigation bar and add `Shell.TitleView`tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             x:Class="Xaminals.Views.BearDetailPage"             
             Title="Bear Details">

    <Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
        <BackButtonBehavior  IsVisible="False" />
    </Shell.BackButtonBehavior>

    <Shell.TitleView>
        <HorizontalStackLayout>
            <ImageButton Source="back.png" Margin="0,0,5,0"></ImageButton>
            <Label Text="test title" FontSize="16" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="LightSalmon"  Margin="0,0,10,0"></Label>
        </HorizontalStackLayout>
    </Shell.TitleView>

  
</ContentPage>
```

**Note:**
You can check the official sample here [Shell](https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples/tree/main/7.0/Fundamentals/Shell).

Comment: I have a question for your first answer. Is there any way to change the font family of the back button? I am using the Material Icons font.

2. I tried this method, but there is an uncomfortable gap where the back button is.

Comment: I tried the `Arrow back iOS new ` icon of  [Material+Symbols](https://fonts.google.com/icons?selected=Material+Symbols+Outlined:arrow_back_ios_new:FILL@0;wght@400;GRAD@0;opsz@24) , and added it to my code and replaced the default icon on my app,  and it looks well on my side.

Comment: I want to add it as font and enter it as unicode data.

Comment: This depends on the font image you are using, and you may consider using other images instead.